# How to freeze a keras model in TensorFlow 2.0? (specifically freeze a saved model format to .pb format)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, protocol-buffers, tensorflow2.0

Can any one please explain the procedure to freeze a keras model (saved model format) into .pb format in TensorFlow 2?
Created a sample mobilenet keras model and saved it to the disk in saved model format

```
import tensorflow as tf
#Tensorflow version: 2.7.0
model = tf.keras.applications.mobilenet.MobileNet(
        include_top=True, 
        weights='imagenet', 
        input_tensor=None, 
        pooling=None,
        classes=1000
)
tf.keras.models.save_model( 
        model, 
        *path*, 
        overwrite=True, 
        include_optimizer=True, 
        save_format='pb', 
        signatures=None 
)
```

Then in another file, I need to load the model and freeze it to a .pb format

```
import tensorflow as tf
#Tensorflow version: 2.7.0
model = tf.keras.models.load_model( *path* )

############################################
# Freeze the model to a .pb format
############################################
```

Answer (score 1):

With the advancement of tensorflow 2, freeze model has changed to saved model where instead of a single .pb file(graphdef), you now have saved model:

1. Weights
2. GraphDef (.pb)

```py
import tensorflow as tf
pretrained_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNet()
mobilenet_save_path = 'weights/mobilenet'

# Save to saved model
tf.saved_model.save(pretrained_model, mobilenet_save_path)
```

Note: Saved model format is faster and produce the exact same results

How to use saved model

```py
import tensorflow as tf
model = tf.saved_model.load('weights/mobilenet/')

# Grab this function to run saved model
infer = model.signatures['serving_default'] 

image = 'something.jpg'
img = tf.io.decode_jpeg(tf.io.read_file(image))
img_pre = tf.cast(img, tf.float32) 
img_pre = (img_pre / 127.5) - 1
img_pre = tf.image.resize(img_pre, [224, 224])
img_pre = tf.expand_dims(img_pre, axis=0)
preds = infer(img_pre)['outputs']
```